# Is ther a way to make all devices same scale?

Tags: android

I made a game in android studio, but the scale of everything changes with the device scale, because the scales of the objects stays the same but the scale of the device ist eg.bigger.

Im working with drawables and bitmaps.

Is there a way to keep everything on the same scale related to the devices scale? 
Like if i had a square and the squad should stay half the devices wight

here i create the variables

```
private Bitmap coin; 
private Bitmap paddlePaint;
private Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
```

here is the decoding

```
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
            paddlePaint = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
R.drawable.paddle);
        coin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coin);
```

here are the drawings

```
        if (coinActive) canvas.drawBitmap(coin, coinX, coinY, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX, ballY, null);
```

Thank you,

Florian

Comment: you can make the size of your object's relative to the device scale. If you'd add your code where you create some objects to the question you might get a more detailed answer by this community.

Comment: Ok thanks, i now added code, but i don't know if that helps